# typescript cast number type to never

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo

```js
r = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrOfCourse.length) + 1;
if (arr.indexOf(r) === -1) arr.push(r);
```

I got this error on the r `Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`

[image]

I'm suppose to cast `r` ? If I try to do:
`r:any = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrOfCourse.length) + 1;` nothing change...

Comment: `var arr: number[] = []` should resolve it.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter thanks this is working! But I don't understand why?

Comment: Ts wasn't able to infer the type of elements the array would contain, so it uses the `never` type.

Comment: because a non typed array defaults to the type never. This in turn forces you to strictly define types for variables. How else would typescript know that the array shouldn't contain strings?